# $\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4r+1} - \frac{1}{4r+3}$

Tags: calculus, summation

I have no idea how to convert this to an integral(which has to be done as the answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$)   I assume it may be equivalent to arctan(1).

Comment: Hint: $\frac{1}{1+x^2} = 1 - x^2 + x^4 + \cdots\implies \tan^{-1}x = \int_0^x \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt = x - \frac{x^3}{3} +  \cdots$

Comment: @achillehui How shall I convert it into this form?

Comment: Look at Zaid's answer, you have $$\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{1}{4r+1} - \frac{1}{4r+3} = \sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^r}{2r+1}$$ Using [Abel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem), one can evaluate RHS as $$\lim_{z\to 1-} \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-)^r z^{2r+1}}{2r+1} = \lim_{z\to 1-} \tan^{-1} z = \tan^{-1} 1 = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Thanks @achillehui. figured it out at night. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint :

Notice that for

$$\sum_{r\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^r}{2r+1}$$ is equivalent to $$\sum_{r\geq 0}\frac{1}{4r+1}-\frac{1}{4r+3}$$

by separating the odd and even terms

Comment: I am sorry but I have no idea how to use this hint.Please elaborate.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Leibniz's Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80)?

Comment: Thanks I should have noticed that it is expansion of arctan(x) where x=1.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't really need the integral as you need a closed form, you can note this is the imaginary part of $$-\log(1-i)=\sum_{k\geqslant 1}\frac{i^k}{k}=\frac{i}{1}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{i}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac i5-\cdots$$ What is $\Im(-\log(1-i))$?